# Table views in Windows Phone 7

Tags: uitableview, windows-phone-7, scroll, tableview

Does Windows Phone 7 have anything like iPhone's UITableView?

[Basically, I'm porting an iOS app where the table views worked really well.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine that the closest match is the `Grid` control, which enables you to define rows and columns and add content to grid cells. You might find the MSDN page [How to: Create a Grid Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752271.aspx) helpful.

Answer (score 4):

you can create something similar to Table view using the below XAML Code.

```
              <ListBox >

                <ListBoxItem>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"   >
                        <Border BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="#A5FFFFFF" Width="80" Margin="0,20,0,20" Height="60">
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl, Mode=OneWay}"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="80" Height="60" Stretch="Fill" />
                        </Border>
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Foobar" FontSize="40" FontWeight="Normal" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="30,0,0,0" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"   >
                        <Border BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="#A5FFFFFF" Width="80" Margin="0,20,0,20" Height="60">
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl, Mode=OneWay}"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="80" Height="60" Stretch="Fill" />
                        </Border>
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Foobar" FontSize="40" FontWeight="Normal" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="30,0,0,0" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox>
```

The above example will create a table view with two elements .If you want you can Add `Border` to seperate between each table.

Hope it helps.